# Output MySQL query as a link

Tags: php

I have a database/table.

Columns are,  id, link, url, name, surname

I have created the webpage that outputs all this, except id and url into a table and it works as I want it to.

What I would like to do is where there is an entry into the link field and also the corresponding url field is to be able to have the link clickable and take you to the url that is in the url field. This is an internal url to the website which is a genealogy website. The links look like this `/getperson.php?personID=I42&tree=Family1`

Is this possible and how would I implement it?

Very new to using databases like this, but ten+ years off using database driven websites, Drupal etc.

First I started with this

```
<td><?php echo $rows['link'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['name'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['surname'];?></td>
```

which would output
I42 John Doe

I got as far as this

```
<td><a><?php echo $rows['Url'];?></a></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['name'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['surname'];?></td>
```

which would output
/getperson.php?personID=I42&tree=Family1 John Doe

I know about hyperlinks in html `<a href="">Link</a>` but as yet I don't understand how to implement that in the above so that when I click on I42 it takes me to the page of /getperson.php?personID=I42&tree=Family1

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73919845/edit) to include an example of your current code, so that we may suggest changes to it.

Comment: Seems like your question is about [creating hyperlinks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Creating_hyperlinks).

Answer (score 2):

```
<td><a href="<?php echo $rows['Url'];?>"><?php echo $rows['link'];?></a></td>
```

Is it this you are looking for? Maybe use `urlencode()` on the URL if not already used when storing it in the DB.

Comment: That didn't work, but before I saw your response I eventually found this and it works <td><?php echo "<a href='".$rows['Url']."'>".$rows['Link']."</a>"; 
?></td>